# Display the number of days between system date and 1st January 2011

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please can anyone help me how to find number of days between current `sysdate` and a specific date?

If we insert that day in any column then we can do it but I want to find directly.

Comment: let's see an attempt...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '20110101', GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

`select sysdate-hiredate xyzzz from emp;`
this is also one process